# How AWS Beanstalk Use Commands to Restart Application Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-beanstalk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blx7r.png)

I know beanstalk deploy program use "eb deploy" command.

If I want to use commands to Restart Application Server of AWS Beanstalk ?

Is there a command to carry out this goal ?

Answer (score 4):

Not using EB CLI, but using the standard AWS CLI it is possible. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/restart-app-server.html

```
aws elasticbeanstalk restart-app-server --environment-name my-env
```